# how to access R variables in a different environment in a python chunk

Tags: python, r, environment-variables, reticulate

I want to pass a variable that's not in the R global environment into a python chunk (using reticulate). Here is an example:

```
library(reticulate)

newEnv <- new.env()
newEnv$x <- 9

z <- 3
```

```
print(r.newEnv$x)
```

This yields an error. Note that I also tried `print(r.newEnv[['x']])`. Also, `print(r.z)` gives `3.0`, as expected. Finally, I've played around with stuff like `eval()` and constructing strings to pass to Python and so far no dice.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of works if you copy your second `Env` into a list first:

````
```{r}
library(reticulate)

newEnv <- new.env()
newEnv$x <- 9
newEnv$df <- data.frame(1:10,1:10)

newEnvCopyDummy <- as.list(newEnv)

z <- 3
```
````

And then your

````
```{python}
print(r.newEnvCopyDummy)
```
````

returns:

```
{'x': 9.0, 'df':    X1.10  X1.10.1
0      1        1
1      2        2
2      3        3
3      4        4
4      5        5
5      6        6
6      7        7
7      8        8
8      9        9
9     10       10}
```

But admittedly, this is not exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! It all works fine if I copy the environment-specific objects into the R global environment, so I can always continue doing that (but that, of course, sort of defeats the purpose of having that other environment in the first place).